# Access to mongo db failed

Tags: mongodb, centos7

I must install mongodb in centos 7 so I use yum:

```
yum install mongodb
```

But when I write "mongo" in console I see this error:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27010 reason errno:111 Connection refused
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you start it / did you read the docs? https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Comment: You need to start the mongodb server. The command is `mongod`. Just running `mongod` may work if database location is at expected/default location. Otherwise you will have to do additional setup, document referred to by @PeeHaa is a good place to start.